# dlib with QT MinGW slow even in Release mode

Tags: qt, mingw, dlib

I am compiling `dlib 18.18` on Windows 10 for `QT 5.6` with `MinGW 4.9.2`.

I have read all recommendations (http://dlib.net/faq.html#Whyisdlibslow): AVX or SSE4 instructions, Release mode.

The example "webcam_face_pose_ex.exe" works like a charm and *really fast*.

**The problem:**

But when I use the frontal_face_detector under QT the framerate is *really low*.

- 640x480 ~170 ms
- 1920x1080 ~1100 ms

System configuration: Windows 10 (x64), Intel Core i5-3550, QT 5.6, OpenCV 3.1.0, MinGW 4.9.2

Tried all variations of using AVX/SSE4 instructions in dlib and opencv.
But I think that it's something different - since the example is fast.
Code used in QT is copy-pasted from the example as well, even without the GUI.

In Debug mode 640x480 frames take 6-7 seconds to process.

**.pro file dump:**

```
DIR_DLIB = "$${LIBSDIR}dlib/dlib18.18/"
DEFINES += DLIB_ENABLE_ASSERTS
LIBS += -luser32 -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -limm32 -lwinmm
INCLUDEPATH += "$${DIR_DLIB}include"
DEPENDPATH += "$${DIR_DLIB}include"
LIBS += -L"$${DIR_DLIB}lib"
LIBS += -ldlib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dlib face detector is header-based and does not depend on the compiler flags used to compile dlib.lib itself.

Dlib has a documented option "-DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=ON", but it will not work if you are not building with CMAKE and including dlib/cmake file into your CMakeLists.txt

You should add AVX enabling flags for compiler into your project to make it work fast

The solution is to add an explicit parameter to your .pro file:

**QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -mavx**

When you are compiling project in Qt Creator, you can see how does it call compiler and what flags are used. Ensure you have -mavx flag. -msse2 will work about 20% slower

Comment: Yes! Brilliant!
Now 1920x1080 goes for 400 ms, 640x480 - 60 ms